# How to create a report in VB.NET based on a single record (specifying the key record at runtime)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, rdlc

I have been searching for days and I've found a lot but it doesn't always make sense. I am trying to create a one page report in a desktop VB.NET application (using Microsoft Report & `ReportViewer` so that installation of external utilities is not required on the client machine) that displays information from one record of a query (the query has multiple joins between tables and works just fine in access).
I have managed to create a `datasource` with a `dataset` showing the query results in the designer and have built the report to look how I like by dragging the objects from Report Data/DataSets onto the report. How do I specify at run time which record from the query I want to display?
Originally, I created a function that takes the record ID and returns a `DataSet` containing the record I require, that is how my form displays the information (data edits and additions are handled separately). Is there a way I can change the datasource for the report at runtime to this function and then send the report direct to PDF or printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the datasource at runtime using this bit of code:

(rv1 is the reportviewer you are using)
    dim bs as bindingsource

```
    rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    rv1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "namespace.ReportName.rdlc"

    bs.DataSource = dsyourdataset
    bs.DataMember = "tablename"
    Dim rds As New ReportDataSource
    rds.Name = "nametomatchnameonreport"
    rds.Value = bs
    rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
```

As for printing directly with no GUI, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx) has some code you can use.